# Can I seperate dependent variables in this way?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be random iid with parameter $\theta$

Suppose $T_1=t_1(s)$ and $ T_2=t_2(s)$ are two unbiased estimators of $\tau(\theta)$ where $s=s(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ is a complete and sufficient statistic.

In the text it then went on to say $E(T_1-T_2)=0$ before going on to prove a theorem. It seems very reasonable but how would you show it?

Using law of iterated expectations we see that
LHS${}= E(E(T_1-T_2\mid S))$

Is the argument just that for the eexpected difference to be non zero, $T_1$ or $T_2$ would have to be consistently different to the other. if $T_1$ consistently estimates lower or consistently estimated higher than $T_2$, then either $T_1$ or $T_2$ would have to be bias which contradicts the assumption. Is that the reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

Since $T_1$ and $T_2$ are both unbiased for $\tau(\theta)$ we have 
\begin{align}
E_\theta(T_1) = \tau(\theta) \qquad\text{and}\qquad E_\theta(T_2) = \tau(\theta).
\end{align}
It then follows that
$$
E_\theta(T_1-T_2) = E_\theta(T_1) - E_\theta(T_2) = 0.
$$